# Measures of non-injectivity?

Tags: information-theory

A function that maps $n-2$ out of $n$ elements of $X$ to a unique element in $Y$, can be thought of as "almost injective" for very large $n$. I'm curious whether there are good **measures of non-injectivity**.

One measure I can think of is the following: for a function $f:X\to Y$, define the degree of of injectivity to be $\frac {I(x,f(x))} {H(x)}$ where $H(x)$ is the entropy of $x$ taken from a uniform distribution over $X$, and where $I$ is the mutual information:
$$H(x)=\mathbb E[\log|X|]=\log |X|$$
$$I(X,f(X))=\log|X|-\mathbb E[\log |\{\tilde x |  \tilde x\in f^{-1}(f(x))\}|]$$
Where the $\mathbb E$ are taken over uniform distributions of $x$.

**Is this a "good" (i.e. with helpful properties) definition of "degree of injectivity"? Are there others?**

Comment: I believe it is related to generated sigma-algebras by random variables when we are in the measure theory situation.

Comment: I had a similar intuitive connection to entropy [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891045/how-to-quantify-deviations-from-bijectivity), and just saw your post.